# Asp.net - prevent parameters replication during redirection to login page

Tags: asp.net

Asp.net, when it sees an unauthenticated request, typically send the request to the login page.

An example is below:
http://localhost:9001/?a=x&b=y&c=z

Request to the login page:
http://localhost:9001/Account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f%3fa%3dx%26b%3dy%26c%3dz&a=x&b=y&c=z

Notice how Asp.net creates a new parameter ReturnUrl but still retains the original parameters while redirecting to the login page.

I have a situation where the initial url length is around 1000+ characters and after this redirection, it becomes 2000+ which is kind of going beyond some browser limits.

Is there a quick way (configuration/httpmodule etc) to prevent the automatic parameters forwarding to the login page? (I can manage the login page needing these parameters to be extracted from ReturnUrl.)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is wondering about this issue, the issue happens even in a default asp.net application but I was able to implement a fix for it.

Following is the fix:

- Implement an HttpModule; handle the EndRequest event and check for 302/unauthenticated request
- We have to use Response.RedirectLocation for most steps below
- Using HttpUtility.ParseQueryString, get collection of all parameters
- Using HttpUtility.ParseQueryString, get collection of all parameters within ReturnUrl value
- Except ReturnUrl, strip out all other parameters which exist in ReturnUrl value
- Update Response.RedirectLocation with ReturnUrl and remaining parameters (none in most cases), Url encoding as necessary

This will ensure the Url now has only ReturnUrl and other parameters which aren't copied in ReturnUrl.

You need to ensure that the login page (Account/Login in above e.g.) does not use any of these parameters or if they do, you have code to pull those out from value of ReturnUrl.

Hope this solution helps anyone with similar situation.